# class not declared in scope but the class is declared

Tags: c++, header-files

I don't know how to describe this but I declare a class (movableBox) but am not able to use in a specific scope (this scope is in the class player).

Here is some of my code:

player class:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "movablebox.h"

class player
{
    public:
        sf::RectangleShape* player;
        sf::Texture* playerTexture;
        sf::Vector2f speed;
        bool touching;

        static void create(sf::Vector2f pos_);
        static void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
        static void updatePos(float& dt, float gravity, std::vector<sf::RectangleShape*> solids, std::vector<movableBox::movableBox_*> movableBoxes);
        static void checkControls();
        static void checkControlsperEvent (sf::Event& event);
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

and the movableBox class:

```
#ifndef MOVABLEBOX_H
#define MOVABLEBOX_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "player.h"

class player;

class movableBox
{
    public:

        struct movableBox_ {
            sf::RectangleShape* box;
            sf::Texture* texture;
            sf::Vector2f speed;
            bool selected;
            player* selectedBy;
            bool touching;
        };

        static void create(sf::Vector2f pos_, sf::Vector2f size_);
        static void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
        static void updatePos(float& dt, float gravity, std::vector<sf::RectangleShape*> solids);
        static void grabNearest(player* player);
};

#endif // MOVABLEBOX_H
```

I'm getting this error:

```
CodeBlocksProjects/phys/player.h:18:110: error: ‘movableBox’ was not declared in this scope
```

As you can tell by my lack of explaination I don't know why or how this happens, I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You are including recursively `moveable.h` and `player.h` in each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a circular dependency issue. There's `#include "movablebox.h"` in `player.h`, and also `#include "player.h"` in `movablebox.h`.

You have forward delcared class `player` in `movablebox.h` and it seems to be enough; so just remove `#include "player.h"` from `movablebox.h`.